# Implementing Webservice client on websphere 8.0

Tags: web-services, websphere, weblogic, axis

I have a wsdl file, the clients files were generated and implemented in weblogic(6 years back).

Now, we are trying to implement in WAS 8.0, i generated the JAX-WS client classes and also developed the client. (we deleted all weblogic related jars)

But, i am receiving the following exception when running it,

```
[8/14/13 17:55:58:368 EDT] 0000001a DispatchActio E org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction dispatchMethod Dispatch[/scrflidverification] to method 'init' returned an exception
                                 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.LookupDispatchAction.execute(LookupDispatchAction.java:160)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.presentation.struts.action.base.BaseLookupDispatchAction.execute(BaseLookupDispatchAction.java:68)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.presentation.struts.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:46)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.frameworks.presentation.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:28)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:883)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1659)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.wstx.handler.WSATGenerator (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.handleInbound(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.wstx.WSTXClientTCMImpl.cleanupContext(WSTXClientTCMImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.ThreadContextMigratorUtil.performContextCleanup(ThreadContextMigratorUtil.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.postExecute(AxisInvocationController.java:654)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:586)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:373)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:171)
    at $Proxy100.invokeIdentityService(Unknown Source)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.applyforbenefits.idverification.IdVerificationServiceImpl.verifyIdentity(IdVerificationServiceImpl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy43.verifyIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at dcf.ess.nextgen.ssp.presentation.struts.action.IdVerificationAction.init(IdVerificationAction.java:114)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(initialization failure)` means that some prior error has occurred that is causing this class to not be loaded.  Is there any additional `Caused by:` that you have not included?  If not, I recommend looking elsewhere through your logs for a stack trace that includes `WSATGenerator.<clinit>`, which should have the original exception.  If you can't find anything, then I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.